# My Chromebook has no "calendar" option in chrome://flags so how would I add a calendar widget to my system shelf?

Tags: calendar, chromebook

I need a calendar widget. Not my own calendar, just a regular calendar showing months and days of the week.  But none of the instructions I've found online for adding a calendar widget to the system shelf match what I see on my Chromebook. When I search for "calendar" in `chrome://flags` area nothing is found.  Are some Chromebook devices too old to support experimental features just as some phones were unable to a install newer version of Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, no sooner had I posted this question than a raft of Chromebook updates was available, even though I'd been using it for a couple of weeks. After one of the updates a date widget was visible on the shelf and tapping it opens a calendar.